How to number the enumerations in a proof environment?
Sometimes when writing a proof I find myself needing to write multiple lists of conditions. This can get rather messy as I want to refer to "condition (3)" but it's not clear which list of conditions I'm referring to!
The paper "In search of Ultimate L" by Woodin has an elegant solution to this problem: there is a counter which starts at the beginning of each proof, so that the Mth entry in the Nth enumeration in the proof is listed as (N.M). To demonstrate, here's an excerpt from a typical proof:

(To my knowledge, the TeX of "In search of Ultimate L" is not publicly available; the paper is not on the arXiv.) Of course, one can use \item with suitable [parameters] to manually make these sorts of "double enumerations". Is there some code I could put in the preamble to automatically make enumerations in proofs have this property?
To me, a typical proof environment containing lists of conditions looks something like this:
\documentclass[reqno,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,graphicx,mathrsfs,url,slashed,subcaption}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Red,citecolor=Green]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{amsxtra}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Every $\infty$-harmonic function $u$ absolutely minimizes $|du|$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
For every $x \in U$, there is a Lipschitz curve $\gamma: [0, T] \to U$ such that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\gamma(0) = x$.
\item $|\gamma'(t)| \leq 1$ for $t \in [0, T)$.
\item $u \circ \gamma$ is convex on $[0, T)$.
\end{enumerate}
So if the theorem does not hold, we can choose $\gamma$ so that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $T < \infty$.
\item $\gamma(t) \to \gamma(T) \in \partial U$.
\end{enumerate}
This is a contradiction.
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Welcome! There is certainly some code you could put in your preamble which would achieve this result, provided your proofs are marked up in some suitable manner. In order to help people figure out what code might work, however, we need you to provide a minimal working example i.e. code we can compile to reproduce the format one of your proofs has at the moment.

Thanks! Is the minimal example that I've proposed acceptable?

Well, really it should only load packages actually needed to set up the problem. But I've seen (much) worse ;). But it compiles, which is very good (and surprisingly unusual.) You want the numbering to restart for each proof, is that right? So if you have a second proof, it should start 1.1?

Yes, something like that: a new proof would start again at (1.1), if possible.
(I couldn't quite remember which packages I was using, and figured having a few unnecessary packages would be better than noncompiling code... but now I wonder why I didn't remove the obviously unnecessary ones like graphicsx...)

You can also test to make sure it compiles rather than guessing ;).

Off topic:  In amsart, amsthm is built in and amsmath is automatically loaded, so \RequirePackage for those is unnecessary.  This is documented.

@barbarabeeton Thank you. I tried to check that, but couldn't find a fast way.

@cfr -- Hmm ... texdoc doesn't seem to bring it up.  I usually check on CTAN for a package, and I found the user documentation for amsart when I searched there.  The information about amsthm and amsmath is on p.6 of the author handbook  (In practically the same words as my comment.  But then, I wrote most of the AMS author handbooks.)

@barbarabeeton I tried to see what amsart.cls Required, but that didn't work well because the code isn't loaded separately. But I did make some effort to check before I wrote my answer. Anyway, I deleted it now.

@barbarabeeton Actually, texdoc does bring up the AMS author handbook but searching the PDF for amsart doesn't find anything, so it isn't obvious it's the right documentation. (Try texdoc autoref. On my system it brings up something about calculating the areas of circles with lorem ipsum text.)

@cfr -- Aha!  The title of the manual is "AMS Author Handbook: Journal Classes".  It covers all the journals published by AMS, and they're all based on amsart.  But you're correct -- that name doesn't appear anywhere.  You may be the first to notice that; at least you're the first to mention it.  Well, not my problem any more, but I'll mention it.

I wouldn't use enumerate (directly) for the job. Maybe you find yourself in need to use a “real enumerate” in your proofs.
\documentclass[reqno,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newlist{prfenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[prfenum]{
  nosep,
  label=(\theprfenum.\arabic*),
}
% a counter for the enumerations
\newcounter{prfenum}
% the counter should be reset at each proof
\AddToHook{env/proof/begin}{\setcounter{prfenum}{0}}
% and stepped at each prfenum call
\AddToHook{env/prfenum/begin}{\stepcounter{prfenum}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Every $\infty$-harmonic function $u$ absolutely minimizes $\lvert du\rvert$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
For every $x \in U$, there is a Lipschitz curve $\gamma: [0, T] \to U$ such that:
\begin{prfenum}
\item $\gamma(0) = x$.
\item $\lvert\gamma'(t)\rvert \leq 1$ for $t \in [0, T)$.
\item $u \circ \gamma$ is convex on $[0, T)$.
\end{prfenum}
So if the theorem does not hold, we can choose $\gamma$ so that:
\begin{prfenum}
\item $T < \infty$.
\item $\gamma(t) \to \gamma(T) \in \partial U$.
\end{prfenum}
This is a contradiction.
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Some comments on your code.

there's no difference between \usepackage and \RequirePackage other than the former is preferred in documents, whereas the latter must be used in packages.

amsmath, amsthm are automatically loaded by amsart;

amsxtra doesn't add any really useful feature;

I wouldn't recommend a long list of heterogeneous packages in a single \usepackage line;

you might find situations where | for the absolute value gives unwanted results, such as |-a|; use \lvert and \rvert instead.



Thanks! I accepted this one, because making a new counter captured the intent of what I was trying to do more accurately than what I was actually describing. (And one of these days I'll clean up my preamble and implement the other changes you're proposing...)

In the following code, I assume that you want the normal enumeration outside of proof environments. It exactly does what you want and doesn't rely on the enumitem package (although it's the right package for such usecases).
Bonus: Make sure that you use the correct \lvert \rvert for vertical delimiters when you denote the absolute value. Better yet, define a new command which encloses the argument. I also corrected the colon symbol to \colon, which is a punctuation, not a relation symbol.
\documentclass{amsart}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcounter{condition}
\AddToHook{env/proof/begin}{
    \setcounter{condition}{0}
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thecondition.\arabic{enumi}}
}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{\refstepcounter{condition}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Every $\infty$-harmonic function $u$ absolutely minimizes $\abs{du}$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
For every $x \in U$, there is a Lipschitz curve $\gamma \colon [0, T] \to U$ such that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\gamma(0) = x$.
\item $\abs{\gamma'(t)} \leq 1$ for $t \in [0, T)$.
\item $u \circ \gamma$ is convex on $[0, T)$.
\end{enumerate}
So if the theorem does not hold, we can choose $\gamma$ so that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $T < \infty$.
\item $\gamma(t) \to \gamma(T) \in \partial U$.
\end{enumerate}
This is a contradiction.
\end{proof}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
\end{enumerate}

\begin{theorem}
Every $\infty$-harmonic function $u$ absolutely minimizes $\abs{du}$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
For every $x \in U$, there is a Lipschitz curve $\gamma \colon [0, T] \to U$ such that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\gamma(0) = x$.
\item $\abs{\gamma'(t)} \leq 1$ for $t \in [0, T)$.
\item $u \circ \gamma$ is convex on $[0, T)$.
\end{enumerate}
So if the theorem does not hold, we can choose $\gamma$ so that:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $T < \infty$.
\item $\gamma(t) \to \gamma(T) \in \partial U$.
\end{enumerate}
This is a contradiction.
\end{proof}

\end{document}



@cfr I think I already used \refstepcounter? And the spurious spaces are not visible since lists (of which proof is also a variant) start in vertical mode, and spaces are ignored in this case. IMO, one should add % only if necessary, e.g. if in horizontal mode.

Sorry, misread the step counter part. I've read it's bad coding style to leave spaces to be inserted even when they won't affect the output. Of course, it increases the work needed for compilation, so maybe that's why. But I don't see why line endings should be commented only when necessary. I can see somebody might say that with today's computation resources, it doesn't matter in these cases. But I don't see there's a "should not".

computation -> computational
